# Classification of the irreducible group representations of the dihedral groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, dihedral-groups

> Let $D_n$ be the dihedral group of order $2n$. Show that all irreducible representations have vector space dimension $1$ or $2$, and describe them up to isomorphism.

Any hints how to even start?

Comment: I suppose what you are looking for is proposition 25 section 8.2 in serre's representation theory finite groups.

Comment: Look at how an irrep restricts to $C_n$.

Comment: It follows from the facts that there is abelian subgroup of index $2$ and all irreducible representations of abelian groups have dimension $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Each irreducible representation of $D_n$ is spanned by at most $[G:H]$ independent vectors for every abelian subgroup $H<D_n$

Let $H=<r> \subset D_n$.

$H$ is clearly abelian and  $[G:H]=2$, hence the result.

if $|H|=n$ is even, there are 4 irreducible representations of dimension 1 and $n/2 - 1$  irreducible representations of dimension 2.