# classification of representations of $D_{1009}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters, dihedral-groups

A follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654770/classification-of-the-irreducible-group-representations-of-the-dihedral-groups/3213669#3213669)

To fix ideas, take $n=1009$.

$D_n$ has $2$ irreducible representations of degree $1$ and $504$ representations of degree $2$.

- Are the degree 1 representations all isomorphic?
- Are the degree 2 representations all isomorphic?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, they mean "non-isomorphic ones". Otherwise it does not make any sense to count them really.

Comment: When we say "such group as this many irreducible representations", clearly it means "non-isomorphic". If you allow isomorphic representations then you have an infinite number.

Comment: Many thanks! TobiasKildetoft and Captain Lama. It makes sense to me now